# How to limit the view of a table in index page based on the logged user with multiple dependencies?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

The following code is in the already generated index class in projects controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var x = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        var projects = db.projects.Include(p => p.area1).Include(p => p.Currency1).Include(p => p.priority1).Include(p => p.program).Include(p => p.projectCategory).Include(p => p.statuss).Include(p => p.statuss1);
        return View(projects.ToList());
    }
```

so I would like to show only few fields from projects table in index view based on the logged user>.

we have 3 linked tables (Projects , Stakeholders and users)

> projects is linked to stakeholders and stakeholders is linked to users in which the logged user is referring to it

Project 1 has many stakeholders (stakeholder 1, stakeholder 2 and stakeholder 3)

> Stakeholder 3 is the user x in users table with logged email x@x.x

How can I go through all these dependencies to verify the logged user by his/her email to show in index the only projects which that user is involved in?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Projection query, here is a simple example below.

```
var test = db.projects.Where(s => s.FirstName == "Bill")
                        .Select(s => new
                        {
                            Student = s,
                            Grade = s.Grade,
                            GradeTeachers = s.Grade.Teachers
                        })
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```